# NetTopologySuite - how to detect when rectangle intersects circle?

Tags: c#, .net, intersection, nettopologysuite

I have the following problem. I own a set of circles that have their own diameter. And I have one square that moves. Using the NST library, I would like to get the information which circle has intersected with the square. What type of Index should I use. Is it at all possible to obtain this?